# CodeIgniter server based 404

Tags: codeigniter, xampp, http-status-code-404

I've installed CodeIgniter on my localhost xampp server in the directory:

```
localhost/CI/
```

When I visit that directory directly I get to see the homepage but when I try to vist any other page I get a server based `404` page. I don't get the see the CI 404.

I already tried playing around with the `uri_protocol` but I can't get it to work. Any clue?

**routes.php**

```
$route['page/create'] = 'page/create';
$route['(:any)'] = 'page/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'page/view/hello-world';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

**Page controller**

```
class Page extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('page_model');
    }

    public function view($slug)
    {
        $data['page'] = $this->page_model->get_page($slug);

        if (empty($data['page']))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = $data['page']['title'];

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('page/view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $data['title'] = 'Create a new page';

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);   
            $this->load->view('page/create');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->page_model->set_page();
            $this->load->view('page/success');
        }
    }
}
```

The "Hello world!" shows nicely, but I can't get the create page to work. The view is located in `views/page/create.php`

Comment: Do you use mod_rewrite? If so what does your .htaccess look like? Can you acces other pages in this format: `localhost/CI/index.php/controller/method`?

Comment: If I try to visit other pages in that format I get the CI 404 error. I've added more content to my question above.

Comment: So no `mod_rewrite`in place, since the second format works. We'll need more code to look at. routes.php, controller code that returns 404?

Comment: What's the name of your controller?

Comment: @FabioAntunes "Pag" I added the code above

Comment: And do you have your controller inside any folder or just inside controllers folder?

Comment: It's just inside the controllers folder, saved as "page.php"

Comment: then remove this from your route config file $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';

Comment: How would I ahead and show different pages then? I would like `localhost/CI/about` to show the about page, saved in the database with slug `about`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25691/discussion-between-user2019515-and-fabio-antunes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xampp !!!! is the problem the mode rewite is not working fine wid it .. install apache as a standalone , add php and mysql and you can work fine any way it will cause other erros

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'page/view/hello-world';
```

change that to

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'page';
```

then move it to the top so you have

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'page';
$route['404_override'] = '';
    $route['page/create'] = 'page/create';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

the order of things is inportant inside the routes.php

and inside page.php controler add a function index()

Comment: I've completed the CodeIgniter tutorial on my installation and that worked fine.

Comment: try it on normal apache or on a websterver somewere because anyway if you are going to publish it on a live server beter  develop on a real server not xampp who is buging any way for the template i loked at your code loading 3 views your better try to use partials http://codeigniter.tv/a-15/Codeigniter-layouts-and-partial-views

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll take a look at it, sounds promising.

Comment: @user2019515 i updated the post maybe this will help a bit and plese send also the config.php

Comment: Would you mind joining this chat? So we can talk & keep this clean http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25691/discussion-between-user2019515-and-fabio-antunes

Comment: The reason why I have `page/view/hello-world` rather than just `page` is because I'm using the view method for all my pages. Just one function rather than 2 seems nice, no?

Comment: ddjikic Solved my issue in the chat, the biggest problem was I was trying to acccess pages like this: `localhost/CI/page/create` rather than: `localhost/CI/index.php/page/create`